# How to copy and paste text with formatting removed

Tags: formatting, text, copy-paste

I am using the `clipboard` package to copy and paste some text. When I paste the text, the formatting also gets pasted.

This is a very basic minimal working skeleton of my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{clipboard}

\begin{document}

% Title
\Copy{MyTitle}{
  {\LARGE The main title:\\
    {\large A sub title}
  }
}


% Abstract
% Want the text pasted without formatting above.
\normalsize
\Paste{MyTitle}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to paste the text without formatting, so that it appears as normalize text?

Comment: Unrelated: Do realise that `\LARGE` and `\large` does not take arguments, the font size is still `\large`  after `\large{test}`

Comment: @daleif thank you, you're correct. I modified the post to show better use of the font size commends

Comment: Why don't you fill the clipboard with plain text only and format the title and rest individually?